# Using ocaml Args in program

Tags: parsing, ocaml

I'm trying to create an ocaml program where a user enters input similar to command line arguments, such as......

```
./program
$ -s foo -i 84
$ -s bar -i 22
```

...basically a simple menu program.

I was hoping to be able to use ocaml [Args](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Arg.html) to do this (especially with the 'usage', etc built in), but I realize this is just for the command line.  Is there a way to re-purpose this library to work for in-program user input, or is it better to hack something together from the [Stream/Parser](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html) library or a different solution entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note that the module name is `Arg`, not `Args`.)

The function [`Arg.parse_argv`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Arg.html#VALparse_argv) seems to do exactly what you want if you're willing to write code to break the line into words.

(Note that in a Unix-like system it's the shell, not the `Arg` module, that breaks lines into words. So to use `Arg` this way you have to do what the shell would do.)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jeffrey for the correct API call...  Initially, I couldn't figure out how to use that call more than once (as in the values would get set to the first set you give ONLY), and the trick is you must use the optional argument `?current:(Some (ref 0))` to use the call more than once.

Here is my code if it helps anyone else (note I am NOT checking errors, etc):

```
(* default values *)
let somestr = ref ""
let someint = ref 0
let usage = "usage: set [-s string] [-d int]"

(* from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Command-line_arguments#OCaml *)
let speclist = [
    ("-s", Arg.String (fun s -> somestr := s), ": follows -s sets some string");
    ("-d", Arg.Int    (fun d -> someint := d), ": some int parameter");
  ]

let parseinput userinp =
  (* Read the arguments *)
  Printf.printf "String:%s\n" (Array.get userinp 2);
  Arg.parse_argv ?current:(Some (ref 0)) userinp
    speclist
    (fun x -> raise (Arg.Bad ("Bad argument : " ^ x)))
    usage;
  Printf.printf "Set stuff to:   %d '%s'\n%!"  !someint !somestr 

let  parseit line =
  Printf.printf "processing %s%!\n" line;
  (* TODO rewrite without Str*)
  let listl = (Str.split (Str.regexp " ") line) in
  parseinput (Array.of_list listl)

let _ =
try
  while true do
    let line = input_line stdin in
    parseit line
  done;
  None
with
  End_of_file -> None
```

Compile:

```
ocamlc str.cma -o args args.ml
```

Commands to give it:

```
set -d 8332 -s lalalla
set -d 11111 -s fffffff
```